# Can't send mail in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.net.mail

Guys I am trying to send an email using the code below in ASP.net but it is not working. However, the same code works for win forms. I am using c#. What seems to be the problem?

```
    try
    {
        using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
        {
            message.To.Add("//some id");
            message.Subject = "New Ticket Generated";
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("//id");
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = "This is message body";

            using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.Host = "// smtp host";
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("// username", "// pass");
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
         }
    }
    catch { }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_ ? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: I have a reponse.redirect code below this code. So I get redirected to that page instantly and there is no exception and neither I receive any mail.

Comment: Remove the exception handling and see what happens.

Comment: Try this:  catch (Exception ex){ Response.Write(ex.Message);}

Comment: Some suggestions: Does `message.To.Add("");` contain a valid E-mailaddress? Does `message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("");` contain a valid E-mailaddress? Did you use the correct `Networkcredentails`?

Comment: You don't get an exception because you're catching it and doing nothing. As suggested, either remove the try/catch, or actually catch the exception. It's also possible that the code is working properly and a firewall is catching the emails thinking you're unknowingly hosting a spam bot.

Comment: Why is there a try catch if you do not handle exceptions anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have missed some codes to write to work it in asp.net

```
codes are
smtp.Port = "port number";
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

follow these are some codes which may help you

```
try
    {
        using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
        {
            message.To.Add("to emailadress");
            message.Subject = "New Ticket Generated";
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("from emailaddress");
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = "This is message body";
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourEmailid", "yourpassword");
            smtp.Send(message);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

N.B- here i am  using gmail smtp server and port, for that you must use an gmail Email address in "from emailaddress" and in smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("the same email-id from emailaddress", "the password of the from emailaddress ");

for example

```
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("rahul@gmail.com");
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("rahul@gmail.com", "myp@ssword");
```

follow this link to get reference of all smtp server details
http://www.arclab.com/en/amlc/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html

try it and goodluck

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers!
Adding these two lines in my code solved my problem :

        smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Check the line in your code **message.To.Add("//some id");** and make sure it's something like **mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@company.com"));** //Make sure correct email address
- Catch and handle (i.e. log, display exception message).  If you don't catch here and let the exception propagate up to the caller, the caller needs to catch and handle.
- Refer to the documentation

  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

and look at all possible exceptions that SmtpClient.Send() method can throw.  More than likely, I think it's SmtpException that gets thrown or a little less likely SmtpFailedRecipientsException.

- Without knowing your environment, I'm guessing you are trying to run this program from your desktop.  Check with your system admin that no virus program such Symantec Endpoint Protection or something like that blocks the smtp port.  If you indeed run from the server, check anyway that the port is not blocked and/or the smtp server dns name is correct (try IP address instead).